# problemas con galería dinámica

Tags: php

Estoy trabajando en una galería de imágenes dinámica. La idea es tener en una misma carpeta una subcarpeta principal con una imagen de referencia de un proyecto (por ejemplo, el currículum de un desarrollador en formato jpg) y varias subcarpetas más, todas numeradas y en cada una de ellas varias imágenes más (por ejemplo, un portafolios con imágenes de otros proyectos). Necesito que se haga un recorrido por cada subcarpeta numerada y si hay alguna con más de 10 imágenes, se muestren las imágenes como una galería. El código tiene un problema de sintaxis y no sé como solucionarlo. Agradezco vuestra ayuda.

```html
        <?php
        //creo directorio con imágenes referenciales
        $pathPrincipal = "img/principal/";
 
        //creo directorios con imágenes de cada proyecto
        $path.$i = "img/" . $i . "/";
 
        //creo array con imágenes referenciales
        $arrayPrincipal = Array();
 
        //creo array con imágenes de cada proyecto
        $array.$i = Array();
 
        //hago un recorrido por el directorio principal 
        //guardo las imágenes en el array
        //guardo la longitud del array en una variable
        foreach(glob($pathPrincipal . '*.jpg') as $imageAlbum) {
            $arrayPrincipal[] = $imageAlbum;
            $long = count($arrayPrincipal);
        }
 
        //recorro las carpetas con los proyectos
        for($i = 1; $i <= count($long); $i++):
        foreach(glob($path.$i . '*.jpg') as $image.$i) {
 
            //si alguna carpeta tiene más de 10 imágenes
            if(count($image$i) > 10) {
 
                //muestro las imágenes
                echo '<img src = "' . $image.$i . '">' . "<br>";
            }
        }
        endfor;
        ?>
```

Comment: cual es el error?

Comment: Y en qué líneas? (Parece que hay varios errores en ese código )

Comment: Me indica un error en la línea 29; el error es:     `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ')' in C:\...\galeria.php on line 29;`     Me parece que puede tener que ver con la declaración de la variable $image$i; En el fondo, en vez de declarar varias veces la función glob con $image1, $image2, $image3, hice una concatenación de dos términos en una variable; la primera es $image y la segunda es otra variable que almacena un número que se incrementa con el bucle for declarado más arriba.

Comment: Perdón, la línea 29 es  `foreach(glob($path.$i . '*.jpg') as $image.$i) {`

Comment: Yo definí las variables $path.$i e $image.$i con la idea de tener un código que hiciera un recorido por un grupo de carpetas numeradas. La idea de declarar así las variables es que si yo tengo cuatro carpetas numeradas (1, 2, 3, 4) el código realice un recorrido. Y si agrego dos más (6 y 7), el código actualice la información por si solo, sin necesidad de actualizar el código cada vez. Dicho de otro modo, tener $path.$i e $image.$i es equivalente a tener $path1 con $image1, $path2 con $image2, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Esta sintaxis no es correcta:

```
$path.$i = "img/" . $i . "/";
```

Por ejemplo, si ejecutáramos esto:

```
$i = 1;
$path.$i = "img/" . $i . "/";
var_dump($i);
var_dump($path);
```

La función var_dump() devolvería para cada variable...

```
string(6) "img/1/"
NULL
```

`$path` no recibe ningún valor!

Lo que deberías hacer es usar `$path` como un array, y `$i` como un índice en ese array:

```
$path = array();
$path[$i] = 'img/...';
```

*ACTUALIZACIÓN:*

Primero, notar que este código no es necesario:

```
foreach(glob($pathPrincipal . '*.jpg') as $imageAlbum) {
    $arrayPrincipal[] = $imageAlbum;
}
```

Como `glob()` devuelve un array simplemente alcanza con hacer esto:

```
$arrayPrincipal = glob($pathPrincipal . '*.jpg');
```

Luego, el error estaba en el resto del código. Corregido, queda así:

```
// la inicialización de la variable no tiene que estar dentro del for
$path = Array();

for($i = 1; $i <= count($arrayPrincipal); $i++):

    // Crear un array $files con las imágenes que estén dentro del directorio actual del ciclo
    $path[$i] = "img/" . $i . "/";
    $files = glob($path[$i] . '*.jpg');

    // Mostrar las imágenes si $files tiene más de 10 elementos
    if (is_array($files) && count($files) > 10) {           
        foreach ($files as $image) {
            echo '<img src = "' . $image . '">' . "<br>";               
        }           
    }       

endfor;
```

En verdad, para el uso que se le está dando a `$path`, no sería necesario que fuera un array. Podría quedar simplemente así, dentro del ciclo `for`:

```
$path = "img/" . $i . "/";
$files = glob($path . '*.jpg');
```

Mantuve el array por si usás `$path` en alguna otra parte que no hayas publicado aquí.

Comment: Cambié la sintaxis de directorios como array y he hecho otras correcciones más, ahora el código está más limpio: eliminé la variable de conteo y saqué algunos arrays. Ahora no tengo errores, pero al ejecutar el archivo no logro mostrar nada. Agregué el código más arriba.

Comment: Perdón por la demora! Ahí actualicé mi respuesta con una corrección.

Comment: Gracias CJ Nimes

Answer (score 0):

```html
        <?php
        //creo directorio con imágenes referenciales
        $pathPrincipal = "img/principal/";
        //hago un recorrido por el directorio principal
        //guardo las imágenes en el array
        foreach(glob($pathPrincipal . '*.jpg') as $imageAlbum) {
            $arrayPrincipal[] = $imageAlbum;
        }

        //hago un recorrido con bucle for
        for($i = 1; $i <= count($arrayPrincipal); $i++):
        //creo directorios para funciòn foreach
        $path = Array();
        $path[$i] = "img/" . $i . "/";
        //recorro las carpetas con los proyectos
        foreach(glob($path[$i] . '*.jpg') as $image) {
             //si alguna carpeta tiene más de 10 imágenes
            if(count($image) > 10) {
                 //muestro las imágenes
                echo '<img src = "' . $image . '">' . "<br>";
            }
        }
        endfor;
        ?>
```